# Points to curves in geometry nodes

Tags: node-editor, bezier-curves, geometry

I have a project in which I want to fill a human shape with wire. So I found this great but rather old tutorial online which uses animation nodes:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3CwKkiJZN0&ab_channel=WiresoulStudio

The setup uses a "spline from points" node that simply generates one long curve by connecting a lot of points generated by particles inside a shape.

Is this possible in Geometry nodes? I can only find guidance on connecting two points to make a curve.

Many thanks for your help.